# Remove everything before a certain number of delimiter characters from a file

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, parsing

I have a data file that is comma delimited but there is no new line separating the header field from the data field and that cannot be changed. Additionally there is no new line such as CR/LF anywhere even after the header portion and the only consistency I see is with the delimiter characters. The data is essentially one big string on the same single line with only comma delimiters separating the fields.

### Sample Header Data

```
"success":true,"dev":"id":999999999,"name":"device name","tags":"id":99999,"name":"devicesname","dataType":"Int","description":"my description","alarmHint":"","value":0.0,"quality":"good","deviceTagId":99,
```

### Sample Data with Header and Data

```
"success":true,"dev":"id":999999999,"name":"device name","tags":"id":99999,"name":"devicesname","dataType":"Int","description":"my description","alarmHint":"","value":0.0,"quality":"good","deviceTagId":99,"history":"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:47Z","value":0.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:48Z","value":1.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:50Z","value":0.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:53Z","value":0.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:57Z","value":0.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:16:00Z","value":1.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:16:02Z","value":1.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:16:04Z","value":1.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:16:07Z"1.0
```

Somehow I have to take this data and either parse out the entire header portion such as remove everything before the 11th comma, and then I need to take the rest and parse out to keep only the values of the "value" and "date" fields with a carriage return and line feed after the value field data value.

It seems the field/column name and the actual value of the data in that field are separated by a colon which I throwing me off.

I'm using Windows for this and would prefer a PowerShell solution even if it needs to make .NET call or whatever but I'm open to any Windows solution that anyone has that could make this happen.

I'd be forever grateful and in your debt for anyone that can help me with this as I've been stuck doing so many things for so many hours and just cannot figure out how to do this. The data is coming from a source that the data cannot be changed unfortunately but perhaps there's a method to do this that I've not found.

### Ending Data Reformatted/Parsed

```
"2016-11-05T21:15:47Z",0.0
"2016-11-05T21:15:48Z",1.0
"2016-11-05T21:15:50Z",0.0
"2016-11-05T21:15:53Z",:0.0
"2016-11-05T21:15:57Z",:0.0
"2016-11-05T21:16:00Z",1.0
"2016-11-05T21:16:02Z",1.0
"2016-11-05T21:16:04Z",1.0
"2016-11-05T21:16:07Z",1.0
```

Comment: Start point: `(Get-Content ".\40453833.csv") -split ","` and then iterate above array using `for` loop starting 11th element and stepping by 2. Return here, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] for next help.

Comment: The data looks like some kind of mangled JSON. Where does it come from?

Comment: See if you can get it at some point before it gets mangled, because unmangling it would be a pain in the rear unless you have a very stable data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your data has comma-separated fields, it's not *CSV* data.

There is no header line followed by data lines; instead, there is just a series of name-value pairs on a single line, where the names aren't *unique*.

The following regex-based solution works with your sample input:

```
# Replace the literal with `Get-Content YourFile` to load data from a file.
$s='"success":true,"dev":"id":999999999,"name":"device name","tags":"id":99999,"name":"devicesname","dataType":"Int","description":"my description","alarmHint":"","value":0.0,"quality":"good","deviceTagId":99,"history":"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:47Z","value":0.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:48Z","value":1.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:50Z","value":0.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:53Z","value":0.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:15:57Z","value":0.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:16:00Z","value":1.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:16:02Z","value":1.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:16:04Z","value":1.0,"date":"2016-11-05T21:16:07Z","value":1.0'

# - Remove the part of the line before the first "date" entry.
# - Then extract the values from adjacent "date"-"value" pairs and output 
#   each value pair on a separate line.
$s -replace '^.+?("date":.+)', '$1' -replace '.+?:([^,]+),.+?:([^,]+)', ('$1,$2' + "`r`n")
```